# where i can get cordova based MobileFirst Appcenter Project which should supports MobileFirst8 server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-appcenter

i need IBM app center project so i can make my changes in there. The one i have is mobilefirst version that is devloped using MF SDK7.1. So i'm unable to use Mobilefirst8 server, especially  push notification  for the Appcenter app.Please provide me your suggestions on implementing Push notificaiton for this app. Note: i don't have MobileFirst Server 7.0.

Comment: Currently which version on server you have ?. Are you talking of the application center client installer App ?. If so then the client installer App is under MFP installation directory .../ApplicationCenter/installer. For how to configure push notification refer: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/appcenter/push-notifications/.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i need to enable push notification behavior for the Installer app whereas im seeing the installer app is implemented using MobileFirst SDK 7.1 but i have  MobileFirst Server8. So can i able to enable push notification behavior for this app developed in 7.1 to run MobileFirst server8?

Comment: Have you verified your MFP 80 installation? You will see the Application Center project in there as well

Comment: yes, in the installation directory i could see only Classic Hybrid based AppCenter Project. i don't see Cordova based Appcenter project. Is there any other location where it will be located? @VivinK

Comment: You can get it from npm. Details here:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/appcenter/preparations/#cordova-based-ibm-appcenter-client

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the installer app that is part of 7.x and it should work with 8.0 as well. MFP 8.0 Application center also ships the installer app and that will be the latest one.

Also, there is pure Cordova based installer app and you can directly take it to the Android studio and work there.